# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to understand why my solution to this problem is only partially working.

**Problem**:

Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that each element appears only once and returns the new length.

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

My Solution:

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    
    if (nums.length === 0) return 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] === nums[i-1]){
            nums.splice(nums[i], 1);
        }
    }
    return nums.length;
};
```

This is the outcome I'm getting on leetcode but I don't understand why my solution stops working and the '3s' are not removed?

Output screenshot:

[image: image of the screenshot]

Comment: You iterate *forward* and remove items. Each time you remove, everything *after* that item moves back a slot. So, if you get an array like `[15, 19, 19, 19, 21]` you'd find index 1 and 2 are the same, remove one, then the *new* item in index 2 is `19` from the old index 3. However, you just increase the counter `i` and never check it, moving over to check the (new) index 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you splice an array while iterating over it, the whole array will change *in-place*. For example, let's say that indexes 0 and 1 are duplicates (i is 1). Then, if you remove index 1 from the array, what used to be at index 2 will now be at index 1, and what used to be at index 3 will now be at index 2, etc.

So, you need to subtract 1 from `i` when an element is removed, otherwise the next element will be skipped.

You also have an off-by-one-error - iterate `i` from `1` to `i < nums.length` so you don't go past the end of the array.

You also need to pass the *index* to remove to `splice`, not the *value* to remove.

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] === nums[i-1]){
            nums.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return nums.length;
};
console.log(removeDuplicates([0, 0, 0]));
```

Comment: The alternative is to iterate backwards from `nums.length - 1` to `0`. Then you don't have to worry about maintaining the index, the shifts in elements don't affect the following iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version. Using functions already created

```
let array = new Set(nums);
let values = array.values();
return Array.from(values);
```

Comment: This uses `O(n)` extra memory, which is forbidden

Comment: Didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

This'd also pass just fine on constant memory:

```
const removeDuplicates = function (nums) {
    
    let count = 0;
    
    nums.forEach(function (num) {
        if (num !== nums[count]) {
            nums[++count] = num;
        }
    });
    
    return nums.length && count + 1;
};
```

Comment: your solution doesn't remove the duplicate elements in the original array

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates(nums) {
  let i = 0;
  while(i < nums.length - 1) {
    i += 1 - ((nums[i] === nums[i+1]) && nums.splice(i, 1).length)
  }
  return nums.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# simple solution:

```
public int RemoveDuplicates(int[] nums) {
        if (nums.Length == 0)
                return 0;
        var i = 0;
            var start = 0;
            var end = 0;

            while (end < nums.Length)
            {
                if (nums[start] != nums[end])
                {
                    nums[++i] = nums[end];
                    start = end;
                }
                end++;
            }

            return i + 1;
    }
```